# Get rid of "*.exe has triggerd a breakpoint"-Messagebox

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-debugging

For debugging purposes I use __debugbreak() function calls. 
When debugging in visual studio, this function causes a breakpoint, as expected. 
But before reaching the breakpoint, it presents a message box, "*.exe has triggered a breakpoint". 
Is it possible to get rid of this message box?

Answer (score 0):

The message box is part of the behaviour of the `__debugbreak`compiler intrinsic.

The MSDN article states that:

> Causes a breakpoint in your code, **where the user will be prompted to run the debugger**.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: You are half correct. The message box is not part of the behavior of the intrinsic; you get exactly the same thing when you do `__asm int 3` directly, without using the intrinsic. It is actually part of the *debugger*. When the debugger is attached to a process, it traps all breaks first and prompts you to either break or continue execution. It's a convenience feature, I'm sure. It doesn't happen when running outside of the debugger.